# ASP.NET exception: The value's length for key 'initial catalog' exceeds it's limit of '128'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am self-learning ASP.NET MVC4, and setting up a simple website, I get the error as soon as I hit the register or login button on the site:

> The value's length for key 'initial catalog' exceeds it's limit of
>   '128'.

I have searched for a solution, but the results are mostly about custom login code using a database connection, but I am using the authorization code implemented by default when starting a new project, with AccountController already set up, so I am not able to figure out what is causing the error or how to fix it.

Debugger halts on the this method call:

```
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
```

and hitting step out halts it on this method call:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Both of them inside `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` class.

And since creating a new project, I have clicked on Login or Register for the first time, so I am not sure whether the error exists from the very start or not.

Comment: What is your project name?? This is likely coming from the "initial catalog" that Entity Framework is trying to create on your behalf..

Comment: the name of the project is `AuctionWebsite`

Comment: Have you has a look at your web.config where the Database connection string is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that this has to do with your connection string in web.config
Have a look for the part like:

```
Initial Catalog=aspnet-AuctionWebsite-20130613142210;
```

chances are yours is over 128 chars..

Comment: Or more likely, a syntax-error (missing semicolon) in the connection string, so other fields are incorrectly part of the Initial Catalog.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `connectionString` with the name `DefaultConnection` was missing completely, i set up a new connection string and deleted the default one earlier. Thanks for pointing out that the problem was with the `connectionString`